# Call another controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in controller 1 that return an array of object,

And in Controller 2, I have to loop in the list that I created so i thought that this will work.

```
 $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod").forEach(function(row) 

        { 
            console.log(row.key); 

        });
```

but the object that i'm getting doesn't have the same format that i was expecting , with console.log I saw that object that i'm getting in Controller2 
is like

```
  {name: "CallParentMethod", targetScope: l, defaultPrevented: false, currentScope: null}
```

So how can I loop into an object that I got from another controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass objects to events:

```
function letSomethingHappen() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("CallParentMethod", {
        title: "Let's pass this string!"
    });
}
```

Then in your other controller:

```
$rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(event, passedArgs) {
    console.log(passedArgs.title); // Let's pass this string!
});
```